# work with SQL UPDATE return in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, return-value

Everytime a user logs in, I'll save an ID from him. To limit the spreading of the program, I want to allow each user to have up to 3 devices. This statement fills up the DB with the HardwareIDs

SQL:

```sql
UPDATE  license SET
        hardwareID3 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID2 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID3 IS NULL
                                THEN $hwid
                                ELSE hardwareID3 END,
        hardwareID2 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID2 IS NULL
                                THEN $hwid
                                ELSE hardwareID2 END,
        hardwareID1 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NULL
                                THEN $hwid
                                ELSE hardwareID1 END
        WHERE code = $lic AND $hwid NOT IN (COALESCE(hardwareID1,hardwareID2,hardwareID3, 0))
```

PHP:

```php
$checkhwid = $VBPHP -> uphwid($hwid, $lic);
```

there are 2 problems:

1. when the user logs in with a second id (for exampl "2") 2 times, the value "2" gets also written in the hardwareID3 column.
2. I want to catch if the user tries to login with a 4th ID and return him an error. Sadly I cant work with "true or false" ifs, because when the user logs in with the first id, I'll get "true" as result and if he logs in multiple times with ID 1 I'll get false, because the statement didnt change anything (what is correct).

I'm running out of ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop. Don't use this kind of table structure. Use a normalized design with the hardware IDs stored in a child table. This will prevent you having to write utterly hideous queries like this, and gives you the freedom to increase your device limit in the future by changing a single centralized limit variable. As is, if you want a 4th, 5th, etc.. device you'll have to modify EVERY SINGLE query that touches on the device table.

Comment: Sounds good, but sadly I'm only the little man for the php and the sql statements and not allowed to change the table :/
Anyway, what would be a "normalized design" anyway? a second table with only tha hardwareids and SQL statement like "join" ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization  Generally speaking, you should aim for 3rd normal form. There's higher/lower forms, but 3rd normal is a nice sweet spot for the extra work v.s. the efficiency gains.

Comment: Thanks alot! Sorry if this was a bad question but this is my first project out of my apprenticeship and there I was never allowed to "play" with the databases

Comment: Not a bad question, but the "real" answer is to redo the database layout so it's futureproof. Basically the equivalent of the proper answer to "how do I cut off my head" is "don't", instead of "use a knife".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below you can return error message and catch failed login count

```
        UPDATE  license SET

                errormessage = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID2 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID3 IS not NULL 
    and )$hwid!=hardwareID1 or $hwid!=hardwareID2 or $hwid!=hardwareID2)
    then 'errormessage' else 'allok' end,

                failedlogins = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID2 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID3 IS not NULL 
    and $hwid!=hardwareID1 and $hwid!=hardwareID2 and $hwid!=hardwareID2 
    then failedlogins+1 else failedlogins  end,

                hardwareID3 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID2 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID3 IS NULL 
    and ($hwid!=hardwareID1 or $hwid!=hardwareID2 )

                                        THEN $hwid
                                        ELSE hardwareID3 END,
                hardwareID2 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                        hardwareID2 IS NULL
    and $hwid!=hardwareID1
                                        THEN $hwid
                                        ELSE hardwareID2 END,
                hardwareID1 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NULL
                                        THEN $hwid
                                        ELSE hardwareID1 END
                WHERE code = $lic AND $hwid NOT IN (COALESCE(hardwareID1,hardwareID2,hardwareID3, 0))
```

Comment: thank you for asking on stack, gives me the opportunity to learn ;)

Comment: Oh the errormessage part doesnt work. how can i catch `then 'too many device' else 'allok' end,` the message in php?

Comment: qou just query for the error message, you can do it with a where errormessage!='allok' and set different messages for different scenarios. you are writing it to the DB in this step, you will have to pull it later

Comment: Okay I did it otherway with the error message. I got another problem! When I try your statement, it sometimes works and sometimes not?! By the way: when I enter characters in $hwid the value doesnt enter the db

Comment: corrected, needed some OR's. For the hwid value not being passed to db, do a select instead of update and see what error you might get or what happens, what the result looks like